# angular using library module in library

Tags: angular

I have an angular library,

it is percomponent module, I mean, for example there are two component(A and B) and each them in it's module,
now I want to use component A in component B, so:

```
// in B module
import { AModule } from './../a/a.module';
@NgModule({
imports: [ AModule]
}
.
.
.

// in B component
<a-comp></a-com>
```

code doesn't have error, but when try to build library, i get this error:

**error TS6059: File 'D:/.../lib/components/a/a.component.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'D:...\lib\components\b'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.**

so:
1) is it posible or not?
2) is it good practice? (or I must create a core library, and use core library in other libraies?).

Answer (score 0):

Eg: Component A 's name is **ADemo** I think you can do like this:

```
//In Component B
import { ADemoComponent } from './ademo/ademo.component'; //ademo is the folder include component A, ademo.component.ts is the file name
```

Comment: AComponent is in another module(AModule). first module shold be import.